# Adding all library files in Rails

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

I have about 20 library third party tools that I need integrate with Rails 4 application that I would like to be included in `Asset Pipeline`

Is there a standard way to do this or should I just add all of them separately in javascripts and stylesheets folder?

The problem of doing this way is that each library have mixture of css and js files and a lot of them are referencing and mixing in within the files themselves.

Is the best way to just separate those files one by one?

Answer (score 0):

We use a method we use is to put "constant" files into a directory of their own, and then call the entire folder from `application.js`:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require_tree ./jquery
```

Comment: But shouldn't you put third party libraries in vendor folder instead to satisfy separation of concern?

Comment: Maybe, but the way we see it is that if you structure your app in a way which is the most efficient, it's the best. So for us, putting the JQuery plugin files into their own directory makes the best sense, as we can call them constantly, whilst leaving controller-centric files to load at different times. It's just the way we do it, that's all!